Movesense showcase app unable to update Flash sensor
I'm unable to update a movesense Flash sensor through the showcase app.
Error: operationError(invalid object)
I have attempted using the with and without bootloader. I have attempted to reset the firmware.
Currently the simple ECG logger sample is installed so I was able to update this sensor in a previous attempt.

The “invalid object” error comes when you try to flash sensor with a DFU package that is not compatible with the bootloader on the sensor (or is not DFU package at all). Assuming the DFU package is downloaded correctly, the most common reason is that the Movesense Flash sensor being updated with the non-flash firmware, or vice versa. You can recognize the DFU made for Movesense Flash looking at the file name, it should have “SS2_NAND” in it. In case you are using your own custom built firmware, you’ll need to follow the build instructions for Flash sensor at: https://www.movesense.com/docs/system/hw_variants/#movesense-sensor-hardware-variants
Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team
